# Filter subclass entities of the supclass single table with JpaRepository

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a supclass named Vehicle which is abstract and extended by two subclasses Car and Motorbike.

On the DAO layer I created just one interface repository for the Vehicle **single table** which includes all the vehicle types (cars and motorbikes), in this repository interface I need to create a methode findCars which returns just Car entities from the main table Vehicle, and another methode findMotorbikes which returns Motorbike entities, how can I manipulate that please.

This is the code of the Vehicle class :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Vehicle")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "Type", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING, length = 10)
public abstract class Vehicle {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String model;
}
```

Car class :

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("Car")
public class Car extends Vehicle {
    private String x;
}
```

Motorbike class :

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("Motorbike")
public class Motorbike extends Vehicle {
    private String y;
}
```